# Регулярное выражение, выбор с конца

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всех с наступающими праздниками!
HELP , запутался с регулярными выражениями.
есть текст:

*Есть много вар**Z**иантов Lorem Ipsum, но боль**Z**шинство из них имеет не**Z** всегда приемлемые модификации, например, юмористические вставки и**Z**ли слова, которые д**Z**аже отдалё**T**нно не напоминают латынь. Есть много вар**Z**иантов Lorem Ipsum, но боль**Z**шинство из них имеет не**Z***

В этом тексте несколько букв **Z**  и одна буква **T**,  между этими буквами произвольный текст.
Как регулярным выражением выбрать кратчайший фрагмент между **Z**  и одна буква **T**, то есть ожидаемый результат: ****Z**аже отдалё**T****  . Как добиться такой работы регулярки?

Comment: Как вариант - `/Z[^ZT]*?T/`

Comment: К чему относится "выбор с конца"?

Comment: выбор с конца - Как понял проблему так и написал, имеется в виду найти ближайший Z к T типо перебор с конца строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак.

Регулярками можно найти 2 подстроки - слева и справа от буквы `T`. Но в большинстве языков регулярки будут выбирать более раннее вхождение, заставить выбрать из двух более короткое - невозможно. Если только это не предусмотрено методами поиска, заложенными в язык.

Comment: Здесь по условию одно-единственное вхождение, выбирать нет необходимости

Comment: @АлексейР, `ZabcZdefTghZijkZ` - надо выбрать кратчайшее из двух: `ZdefT` и `TghZ`.

Answer (score 1):

`Z([^Z]*?)T`

([^Z]*?) - это захватывающая группа, которая соответствует любому количеству символов, кроме 'Z', и делает это лениво (т.е., захватывает наименьшее возможное количество символов).

Comment: "Ленивость" здесь опциональна, работает и без неё. И круглые скобки тоже.

Comment: Выбирает всегда кусок от Z до T и никогда от T до Z.

Comment: @Qwertiy в задании буквально *"выбрать кратчайший фрагмент между Z и одна буква T"*. Вариант "от T до Z" - это по-моему, расширенное толкование задания. Вопрос - а какой фрагмент в этом случае может быть "не кратчайшим"? Например: ZaaaZaaaT. Почему такая логика - вряд ли задание задается для того, чтобы его не решить и сообщить, что регекс на это не способен. Но это мои домыслы :)

Comment: @АлексейР, судя по поставленной автором галочке, я понял правильно. На мой взгляд формулировка "между Z и T" - предполагает просто наличие разных букв с разных концов, а "от Z до T" - уже в конкретном направлении.